# Android studio two of the same button in xml but only one has shadow

Tags: android

In my LoginActiviy, I have **two buttons**. They have the **exact same properties** in the XML but only **the upper button has a shadow** underneath it. The image below demonstrates this

[image: Shadow demonstration]

Here is the XML for the layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<!-- Login progress -->
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/login_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/login"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signInButton"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/continueAsLoggedOutButton"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/continue_as_logged_out"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

What is the cause for this?

Comment: Possibly the `LinearLayout` wrapping is cutting it off? You might try adding a `paddingBottom` on the `LinearLayout`, or a `layout_marginBottom` on the `Button`.

Comment: Thank you, the margin to the button solved it!

Comment: add marginBottom for @+id/email_login_form. Scrollview have fix height..

Answer (score 0):

As [Mike M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m) commented, I added `layout_marginBottom` to the `button` and it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `paddingBottom` on the `LinearLayout`.